# Killing a WinCE device process from a desktop app

Tags: windows-ce, rapi

I'm copying files from the desktop to a WinCE device (via the [RAPI API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921197.aspx)), and if the main WinCE program is running, I need to kill it, update and restart it again.

So far, I manage to copy the files and start the main program with no problem, but I cannot found a way to terminate a process via RAPI (there is a CeCreateProcess function but no CeTerminateProcess or similar)

Currently i'm spawning [RapiProc.exe](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=528548) -k \MyDir\MyProcess.exe and it works, but I cannot find the way to do it via RAPI

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RAPI doesn't provide a direct way to kill a process.  You must create a custom RAPI DLL that provides that capability.  As a good starting point, [this blog article](http://web.archive.org/web/20120112083707/http://blog.opennetcf.com/ncowburn/2007/07/27/HOWTORetrieveTheDeviceIDFromTheDesktop.aspx) shows how to retrieve the device ID via a custom RAPI dll.  Just modify it to broadcast a WM_CLOSE and then a TerminateProcess if that fails.

Comment: And now it's fixed.  Sorcery.