# How start/stop applications on ActiveSync cradled device

Tags: windows-mobile, activesync

Is is it possible to, from a desktop program, start or stop an application or send commands to a cradled Windows Mobile device attached via a USB cradle to the PC?

Scenario: I would like to automate a process that involves closing a (poorly-designed0 application the handheld so that I can backup and remove some of its files which are locked while its running, change some things, and then start a different program on the handheld which automatically recreates some of the files.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920177.aspx) to manipulate the connected device from a Windows desktop application.  There is a [managed C# wrapper](http://rapi2.codeplex.com/) available for managed development.  You can use [C API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921197.aspx) or a COM interface to program RAPI in the native world.

To start a program on the device using the C API, you would call CeCreateProcess.  To kill a process from the desktop you have two options: 1) write a RAPI dll, or 2) write a simple mobile app that closes the process and call this program via CeCreateProcess.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378509/killing-a-wince-device-process-from-a-desktop-app) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the dll OpenNetCF.Desktop.Communication to perform this procedure, but I'm not sure that this library has the ability to close the application, take a look at the website:
http://rapi.codeplex.com/

I checked quickly, and have not found a method to finalize the function, but the CreateProcess method has an output parameter ProcessInfo and this struct has a handle, you can verify that with this information you could terminate the application via CloseHandle.